# Images from director not displayed

Tags: bolt-cms, imagesource

I've recently started experimenting with Bolt-cms and everything has been going smoothly, but this: I'm trying to add some hard coded images to my template, but they don't show up. It looks like the pathing is wrong.

```
<img src="img/test.jpg" >
```

or

```
<img src="{{root}}/img/test.jpg" >
```

don't seem to work.

Does someone know the correct approach is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use Symfony Asset, [docs here](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.2/templating/templatetags#asset).

But the short version:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js', 'theme') }}"></script>
# Include jquery.min.js from the js folder in your theme.

<img src="{{ asset('kitten.jpg', 'files') }}"></script>
# Display the kitten.jpg image, that was uploaded to the `files/` folder.
```